# I want to play a Wav file by voice modem

Tags: c#, modem, voice

I have got a voice modem.
What I want is that the application will call a particular number and when the user picks up the call, a wav file should be played and after it the application will disconnect the call.

Can anyone direct me to the appropriate path.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a legitimate use of this!

Comment: For telemarketing purposes, MPritch.

Comment: Think admin! MPritchard & Akshay J

Answer (score 2):

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set) gives you most of what you need to know. The rest would be encoding the audio to a format the modem supports, and using `+++` to go to command mode on the modem.